# eunit testing for sent messages

Tags: unit-testing, erlang, eunit

I am trying to write eunit tests to check wether a module send messages as it should. I can pass a PID as parameter so that it sends the messages to the testing module. The problem is that it sends messages using `gen_fsm:send_event`.

I have tried implementing the `gen_fsm` behaviour with the testing module and forward incomming messages to the testing functions. However, it does not work, the messages seem to get lost.

Anyone knows how to test for incoming `gen_fsm` messages with eunit??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use an [erlang mocking library](http://github.com/eproxus/meck) to mock out gen_fsm.